# Use standard deviation of sample or population in z test

Tags: standard-deviation, sample, population, z-test

I am reading the book Statistics by Witte & Witte. Some questions puzzle me.

Question 10.9:

> The normal range for a widely accepted measure of body size, the body
>   mass index (BMI), ranges from 18.5 to 25. Using the midrange BMI score
>   of 21.75 as the null hypothesized value for the population mean, test
>   this hypothesis at the .01 level of significance given a random sample
>   of 30 weight-watcher participants who show a mean BMI = 22.2 and a
>   standard deviation of 3.1.

The chapter explains the z test. It uses the following formula.

```
z = (mean_sam - mean_pop) / (stdev_pop / sqrt(n))
```

In the question only a standard deviation of the sample is given. I don't no whether and how this affects this formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different tests (z/Gauss-test and t-test) depending on whether the population stdev is known or the sample stdev is plugged in.

Comment: thank you Then I conclude the question is misguiding.

Comment: Actually for large samples the two are pretty much the same (equivalent for $n \to\infty$), and even for $n=30$ they shouldn't give you something too different.